# Dynamic Form Submission to database

Tags: php, javascript, json, forms

I've got an HTML form that has some static fields and some fields that are dynamically added with javascript. It looks sort of like this

```
<html>
<script type="text/javascript">

        window.onload = function()
        {
            var select = document.getElementById("select");
            var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
            select.onchange = function()
            {
                var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
                texts.innerHTML = "";
                for(i=0; i < val; i++)
                {
                    //texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="t_' + i + '" value="select_' + i + '" /></div>';
                    texts.innerHTML += i + '<div><input type="text" name="t_' + i + '" /></div>';
                }
            }
        }

    </script>
<body>
    <form method="POST" action="connection.php">
Question:<br>
<textarea name="question" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea><br>
<select id="select" size="1">
<option value="1">1</option>
<option value="2">2</option>
<option value="3">3</option>
<option value="4">4</option>
<option value="5">5</option>
<option value="6">6</option>
<option value="7">7</option>
<option value="8">8</option>
<option value="9">9</option>
</select>
<div id="texts"></div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

when the user clicks  it adds a text box field. How does the data stored into the database.Kindly suggest me an idea what are the resources used to do this .Thanks in advance

Comment: whats the  problem now? Whats the result of print_r($_POST) in connection.php when submitting form?

Answer (score 2):

Good day Shashak

In order to submit the data of your form into the database, regardless of the javascript of the form the data should be passed using in your case the POST method to a script 'connection.php' in your case.

This script should contain a way to connect to your database followed by the logic that will validate your data and then at the end if the validation is successful a database query that will INSERT the data into your database.

---

Which is your level of understanding when it comes to PHP or any other server-side scripting language and databases? - I will be able to give you more information if I know what you know.

Comment: I am a newbie to php i have an idea y cant we store all the data in a json string and then to database ?Is it possible ?if not what are the validations should be done before inserting into database Kindly suggest me .Thank you

Comment: Ok, so the data that you are submitting via the form are send with a POST request on the server. These data are stored into the $_POST[] global variable. At your case this will be two variables one coming from your select and one from your input.

These will be accessible like 
$var1 = $_POST['question'];
$i = $_POST['t_1']; // That's an example variable.

Validation has to do with what you want to check against like JS after that. I will suggest you read http://www.w3schools.com/php/default.asp

Comment: My idea was to store the details in the json string and then to database is this the correct idea?

Comment: MongoDB might be something that is going to be easier for you to Use then since it's storing data like this.

Comment: Suppose there are two fields one is question and other one is option where options consists of dynamic text boxes created by the dropdown in this case its 0 to 9. In my database i have only three columns id,question and option.If user enters two options . How the data is gong to be stored in database in that single column.Kindly suggest me Dimitris.

Answer (score 0):

### PHP

It will post data like this:
Suppose you select option 2.

```
$inputs = $_REQUEST['t']; // change the name like this name[]
$textarea = $_REQUEST['textarea'];
$selectbox = $_REQUEST['select']; // you should define the name of the select box as i used 'select'
```

insert into mysql

```
$conn = mysql_connect('localhost', 'db user', 'db password');
mysql_select_db('database name');

for($i=0; i<count($inputs); $i++) {
    $sql = "insert into <table name> (textarea, inputs) values ($inputs[$i], $textarea)";
    mysql_query($sql);
}
```

it will store each row as per your selection of input text boxes.

Note: Modify the query as per your requirement.

Comment: I am defining only one column in database how can i store 2 values at a time?

Comment: you can do it by using for loop on the value of selectbox

Comment: sorry @skparwal i didnt get you can i store it in json? and then to database

Comment: yes you can do it. you need to convert into json using encode_json() php function. for reference site: http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php

Comment: $spkarwal: I am unable to write the for loop condition in this case when the user clicks on submitbutton then it connects to the connection . php where should i include for loop please help me

Answer (score 0):

I think instead of giving the textbox the name format t_1 , t_2 you can give it as an array like below

```
    <html>
   <script type="text/javascript">

    window.onload = function()
    {
        var select = document.getElementById("select");
        var texts = document.getElementById("texts");
        select.onchange = function()
        {
            var val = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value;
            texts.innerHTML = "";
            for(i=0; i < val; i++)
            {
                //texts.innerHTML += '<div><input type="text" name="t_' + i + '" value="select_' + i + '" /></div>';
                texts.innerHTML += i + '<div><input type="text" name="txt_name[]" /></div>';
            }
        }
    }

</script>
 <body>
 <form method="POST" action="connection.php">
  Question:<br>
     <textarea name="question" cols="35" rows="5"></textarea><br>
    <select id="select" size="1">
 <option value="1">1</option>
 <option value="2">2</option>
 <option value="3">3</option>
 <option value="4">4</option>
 <option value="5">5</option>
 <option value="6">6</option>
 <option value="7">7</option>
 <option value="8">8</option>
 <option value="9">9</option>
 </select>
<div id="texts"></div>
<input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Submit" >
 </form>
 </body>
 </html>
```